# VBA to select a portion of range

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a script to select a range of data while skipping any rows that have a blank cell.  The issue is the "blank" cell technically has a formula in it so the script that I have thinks the cell is not blank.  I need to be able to select the rows that have data in the B column and be able to paste into a word document.  I already have the copy/paste part (I use it on other tables), but cannot find how to get this part.

Example spreadsheet:

```
Column A  Column B  Column C  Column D  Column E
  test1     31.2     Windows   text      text
  test2     31.2     Linux     text      text
  test3              Linux     text      text
  test4     31.2     Windows   text      text
```

Columns A, C, D, and E, will always have data, but column B is variable.

What I have in part is:

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E", & LastRow).Copy

Dim RangeToCopy as Range
Set RangeToCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E" & LastRow)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I have searched and cannot find a solution.

Comment: Use, `Filter` to filter out any rows that have a blank.  Then copy the visible rows.

Comment: Note: You are getting the last row from whatever is the `ActiveSheet`, but then you are defining the range to copy using `Sheet1` no matter which sheet is active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Copy Non-Blank Rows

- This will copy the header row and all rows that are not blank in column `B`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyNonBlankRows()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook  ' workbook containing this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    Dim LastRow As Long: LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1:E" & LastRow)
        
    rg.AutoFilter 2, "<>"
        
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = rg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    srg.Copy
    
End Sub
```